# Explode a string by \r\n & \n & \r at once?

Tags: php, unicode

I want to split a string by lines but i want it to be based on all the major used line breaks characters:

- \n
- \r\n
- \r

And return an array containing each line.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use a regular expression and [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) instead:

```
$lines = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $str);
```

The regular expression `\n|\r\n?` matches either a LF or a CR that may be followed by a LF.

Comment: Would it be robuster to put \r\n first? `/\r\n?|\n/`

Comment: @GrasDouble is right, it's incorrect that way as it will leave a \r in the string.

Comment: This answer is all fine, but I find the solution of @jerrygarciuh much more preferable.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 33):

`preg_split('/\R/', $str);`

In PHP preg_split(), preg_match, and preg_replace the `\R` matches all line breaks of any sort.

http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

> By default, the sequence `\R` in a pattern matches  any  Unicode 
>   newline sequence,  whatever  has  been selected as the line ending
>   sequence. If you specify
>
> `--enable-bsr-anycrlf`
>
> the default is changed so that `\R` matches only `CR`, `LF`, or `CRLF`. 
>   What- ever  is selected when PCRE is built can be overridden when the
>   library functions are called.

Comment: Is there documentation for this somewhere? Versions applicable? I don't see it in the manual

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all occourences of breaking characters with a unique placeholder and then explode the string in an array, doing something like this:

```
$my_string = preg_replace(array('/\n/', '/\r/'), '#PH#', $my_string);
$my_array = explode('#PH', $my_string);
```