# How to get strings sentence by sentence in a html textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, string, textarea

I have a text area which contains information as follows,

```
Secured places in the national squad respectively
Selected to the national team this year as well
Selected to the national team twice during his university career
Went to school at ABS
```

**when user click the submit button, I want to get strings in each lines to php variables in submit page**, something like this

```
$a = "Secured places in the national squad respectively";
$b = "Selected to the national team this year as well";
$c = "Selected to the national team twice during his university career";
$d = "Went to school at ABS";
```

can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: list($a, $b, $c, $d) = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']); But if the number of lines isnt allways 4 use array.

Comment: actually you can use the answer to this question as sometimes \n\r is tricky:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/5053373/671943

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about sentences but rather line breaks, you should be able to break into an array based on that like this:

```
$posted_text = $_POST['text']; // or however you get the value into a string
$text_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $posted_text);
```

Comment: Note that `PHP_EOL` may not be the correct EOL, since it is the server's EOL you're splitting on, and not necessarily the users.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for

```
explode('\n\r', $var)
```

where var is the value your ripping apart

Comment: it must be "\n\r" -> double quote

Comment: Are you sure you can't single quotes? :)

Comment: I think that if you use apostrophs it wouldn't work. And its "\r\n" But better is use PHP_EOL constant.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be exploding the string via the newline character \n. Unfortunately, if the user didn't actually hit enter and the text has just rolled onto the next line, there won't be any newline characters to explode by.

Answer (score 0):

Working example wihout breaking lines:

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/OBiUXP

---

```
$words = explode(" ", str_replace("\n"," ",$text));
$sentences = Array();

$sentence = Array();
foreach($words as $word) {    
    $word = trim($word);
    if(!$word) continue ;
    $char1 = substr($word,0,1);
    $char2 = substr($word,1,1);

    if((strtoupper($char1) == $char1) && (strtolower($char2) == $char2)) {              
        if(count($sentence)) {
            $sentences[] = join(" ", $sentence);
        }        
        $sentence = Array();
    }    
    $sentence[] = $word;    
}
if(count($sentence)) {
    $sentences[] = join(" ", $sentence);
}
```